# Videojs flash api currentTime

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-video, video.js

How can I set the currentTime in videojs when browser is not support html5 so it use flash.
If browser support html5 this code is good:

```
player.on("loadeddata", function(){
    player.currentTime(current_video.sec1);
    player.play();
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this "loadeddata" event get dispatched when it falls back to Flash? When it falls back to Flash, is the `player` variable defined? Do you get any errors in the javascript console? It seems like you could debug this a little more, and if you already have, you should be sharing those results w/us ;)